# Unity lifetime manager for EF5 with multi-threading and the repository pattern

Tags: .net, entity-framework, unity-container, .net-4.5

I've seen a lot of Q/As here on SO saying that mlutithreading with EF can be difficult.

The scenario I've got is that a web API queues up jobs in a database. A Windows Service (actually a console app at the moment) picks up those jobs, runs them on multiple threads and stores the results in the database.

I'm using the repository pattern at the moment and tried initially using only the main thread to update the database. This isn't working as work is coming in (much) faster than the main thread can update the database - especially if there are a lot of results (tens of thousands).

The next approach would be to go to context-per-thread which I can do quite easily by changing the lifetime manager on my container but this would (presumably) result in concurrency issues where a worker thread updates the job status to be "complete" but the main thread wouldn't know as it's cached copy is still "In progress".

I suppose the next approach is to have context-per-request but I'm concerned that there will be a lot of setup/teardown - especially with a lot of threads running side-by-side. In any case, I'll give it a go and see how good/bad it is.

Assuming the last option is the way to go, how can I get Unity to resolve the same context per- logical request? That is to say if I do...

```
Dim UnitOfWork = Container.Resolve(Of IUnitOfWork)
Dim UserRepo = Container.Resolve(Of IUserRepository)
Dim RoleRepo = Container.Resolve(Of IRoleRepository)
''Do Stuff
UnitOfWork.Commit
```

I need all the objects to use the same context. Do I need to roll my own lifetime manager and use something unique for each group (say a new Guid)

```
Dim Key = Guid.NewGuid
Dim UnitOfWork = Container.Resolve(Of IUnitOfWork)(New MyLifetimeManager(Key))
Dim UserRepo = Container.Resolve(Of IUserRepository)(New MyLifetimeManager(Key))
```

or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you need just single top level object for your resolving which will be provider of other objects. For example:

```
public interface IDalProvider
{
    IUnitOfWork { get; }
    IUserReposiotry { get; }
    ...
}
```

Implementation of this interface will be resolved by Unity. It is up to you if you will let the implementation to actually create implementations or if you pass them through dependency injection.

In the former case you will inject context instance to the provider implementation and use it internally when constructing unit of work and repository instances. In the later case you will inject context instance directly to unit of work and repository implementations and you will use Per-resolve lifetime for the context, uow and repositories (same instance will be injected to all dependent objects in single resolving).

Comment: Thanks but that raises a different issue - Do I need to construct every repository I could possibly need even to use just 1?

Comment: It depends on the way how repository is implemented - it needs to get current context somehow. Either you will have it passed through dependency injection and in such case you must create it together with a context or you will have completely stateless implementation and pass context to every method call (that would break the meaning of the repository).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but what I meant was in the example about with your `IDalProvider`,  If I've got 30 tables and want to use 2 of them, I need to instantiate 30 repositories - or presumably end up with n-different IDalProviders for different scenarios. Should I be concerned about the overhead of instantiating 30 objects to use 2-3?

Comment: That is why I suggested the first approach as well. In such case the provider will become factory and it will wrap construction of correct repository implementation - you will not have those implementations defined in unity. The implementation will be constructed only when it is needed for the first time.